# Extracting the top-k value-indices from a 1-D Tensor

Tags: python, lua, pytorch, torch

Given a 1-D tensor in Torch (`torch.Tensor`), containing values which can be compared (say floating point), how can we extract the indices of the top-*k* values in that tensor?

Apart from the brute-force method, I am looking for some API call, that Torch/lua provides, which can perform this task efficiently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of pull request [#496](https://github.com/torch/torch7/pull/496) Torch now includes a built-in API named [`torch.topk`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/03c04c6/doc/maths.md#torchtopkresval-resind-x-k-dim-dir-sort). Example:

```
> t = torch.Tensor{9, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5}

-- obtain the 3 smallest elements
> res = t:topk(3)
> print(res)
 1
 2
 3
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 3]

-- you can also get the indices in addition
> res, ind = t:topk(3)
> print(ind)
 2
 4
 6
[torch.LongTensor of size 3]

-- alternatively you can obtain the k largest elements as follow
-- (see the API documentation for more details)
> res = t:topk(3, true)
> print(res)
 9
 8
 7
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 3]
```

At the time of writing the CPU implementation follows a [sort and narrow approach](https://github.com/wickedfoo/torch7/blob/ef019670474b69629a8b3d50eb426d5858bd5c45/lib/TH/generic/THTensorMath.c#L1757-L1769) (there are plans to improve it in the future). That being said an optimized GPU implementation for cutorch is currently being [reviewed](https://github.com/torch/cutorch/pull/296).

Comment: deltheil, I am trying to do what you suggested but I am facing the following error: `res = t:topk(3)
[string "res = t:topk(3)"]:1: attempt to call method 'topk' (a nil value)`; Can you please tell me what is happening?

Comment: Your torch7 install is too old: try installing the latest version (topk has been added recently).

Comment: deltheil, I thought so too. Got it working now. Thanks.

Comment: Could someone please explain the column (`:`) syntax in `t:topk(3)`, which gives me `NameError`, while `torch.topk(t, k=3)`, works as expected?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [topk](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.topk) function.

for example:

```
import torch

t = torch.tensor([5.7, 1.4, 9.5, 1.6, 6.1, 4.3])

values,indices = t.topk(2)

print(values)
print(indices)
```

the result:

```
tensor([9.5000, 6.1000])
tensor([2, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the tensor and run your compare:

```
require 'torch'

data = torch.Tensor({1,2,3,4,505,6,7,8,9,10,11,12})
idx  = 1
max  = data[1]

for i=1,data:size()[1] do
   if data[i]>max then
      max=data[i]
      idx=i
   end
end

print(idx,max)
```

--EDIT--
Responding to your edit: Use the torch.max operation documented here: https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/maths.md#torchmaxresval-resind-x-dim ...

```
y, i = torch.max(x, 1) returns the largest element in each column (across rows) of x, and a Tensor i of their corresponding indices in x
```

Comment: binarymax, do you know how to extract any general top-k values directly like this?

Comment: If you need the indices and not the values, then no.  If you need the values only, then sort the tensor and then slice it.